# Counting items in pandas column of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a dataframe with a column which has dictionaries in it. I want to count the number of occurrences of a dictionary key in the whole column.

One way of doing it is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({"data": [{"weight": 3, "color": "blue"},
{"size": 5, "weight": 2},{"size": 3, "color": "red"}]})

c = Counter()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for item in list(row["data"].keys()):
    c[item] += 1

print(c)
```

Which gives

```
Counter({'weight': 2, 'color': 2, 'size': 2})
```

Are there faster ways of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much faster approach would be to flatten the column with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and build a `Counter` from the result (which will only  contain the dictionary keys):

```
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.data.values.tolist()))
# Counter({'weight': 2, 'color': 2, 'size': 2})
```

---

Timings:

```
def OP(df):
    c = Counter()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for item in list(row["data"].keys()):
            c[item] += 1

%timeit OP(df)
# 570 µs ± 49.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.data.values.tolist()))
# 14.2 µs ± 902 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can using

```
pd.DataFrame(df.data.tolist()).notnull().sum().to_dict()
Out[653]: {'color': 2, 'size': 2, 'weight': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, creating an empty `Counter` is in my opinion pretty useless. `Counter` can count for you if you supply a list to it. It's its main purpose, I would say.

I would do:

```
from functools import reduce
c = reduce(lambda x, y : x+y, [Counter(x.keys()) for x in df['data']])
```

and `c` is:

```
Counter({'color': 2, 'size': 2, 'weight': 2})
```

To explain what the line abobe does, first it creates a list of `Counter` objects using a list comprehension. It iterates over the column and makes `Counter` objects using the keys of each dictionary.
Then using the function `reduce` those counters are summed. `Counter` supports the addition.

On my machine this approach, using the provided input, is roughly 4 times faster than OP method.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly with `pandas` features:

```
In [171]: df['data'].apply(pd.Series).count(axis=0).to_dict()                                                   
Out[171]: {'weight': 2, 'color': 2, 'size': 2}
```